# Automating Firefox' address bar to explore forbidden web folders

Tags: firefox, website

Let's say I'm browsing some web site's folder which includes images: For instance, there is a picture on the following address:

```
http://www.example.com/images/gallery/8392/13.jpg
```

It's not possible to view the *gallery* folder (403 Forbidden) here. For a quick exploration I'll have to type `01` or `1` instead of `13`, and then `2`,`3`,`4` etc. Since this is manual, mostly it's back breaking. Is there a trick or add-on for Firefox to automate this process?

Comment: Hmmm would this addon help: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/591 ?

Comment: It says "Browses all linked images of a page one after another or at once". The problem is, I'm interested in the unlinked images which are inside a forbidden folder.

Comment: I do have to admit that I first heard of the bookmarklets I linked below through one of the Firefox developer's jokey page on how to make make Firefox perfect for browsing *ahem* image galleries: http://www.squarefree.com/pornzilla/ my answer below linked to what I think is the original source of the bookmarklets, rather than a site some may hesitate to visit given the URL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a Firefox [bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/) sitting on my toolbar to do just this, no add-on needed. Bookmarklets are just a single line of Javascript that you save as a bookmark, then when clicked they run on the current page.

If you look at the [Miscellaneous Bookmarklets page](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/misc.html) you should see the Increment and Decrement bookmarklets that search the current URL for a number and either add one onto it, or take one off it. I just save those two to my toolbar and give them the labels "+1" and "-1" so they take up almost no space. Sounds like it's what you're after?

Comment: Superb! More than what I want.